# Что из этого является потоками?

Tags: linux, unix

Доброго времени суток.

Не могу разобраться, что из этого является именно потоками, и как их вообще отличать от процессов.

Самой системы Linux на PC нет, опираюсь на скриншоты.
Именно этот сделан в командной строке с "top H".

Очень надеюсь на Вашу помощь, т.к. сам разобраться не смог, да и в сети что-то так и не нашел однозначного ответа на то, как их отличать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: top H показывает потоки. Всё что вы видите это потоки.

Comment: **Всё что вы видите это потоки** - кто вам такое сказал ?!!! Читаем man: *The  top  program  provides a dynamic real-time view of a running system.  It can display system summary information as well as a list of processes or threads*

А опция *H* означает, что треды печаются отдельно, а НЕ суммируются внутри процесса:

*H - Instructs top to display individual threads.  Without  this  command-line  option  a summation  of  all threads in each process is shown.  Later this can be changed with  the `H' interactive command.

Comment: @Sergey: да, каждая строчка это поток -- всё что вы видите (каждая строчка в таблице) это потоки. Я тоже man процитировать могу: *"top **-H** :Threads-mode operation
            **Instructs top to display individual threads**.  Without this command-line option a summation
            of  all threads in each process is shown."* [выделение моё]¶ Используйте \@-синтаксис, если хотите, чтобы мне уведомления о вашем комментарии приходили.

Comment: Вы как раз и процитировали то место, в котором говорится, что ооция *-H*  показывать треды отдельно. Т.е. можно показывать треды внутри процесса-хозяина, а можно -  отдельно. Но далеко не все процессы содержат треды. Процесс - первичен, а тред - вторичен.

Comment: @Sergey: каждый процесс содержит как минимум один поток, поэтому каждой строчке в таблице соответствует поток¶ У вас похоже проблемы с чтением как документации так и комментариев -- даже после подсказки не способны \@-синтаксис использовать.

Comment: @jfs Я понимаю, что оскорбление - лучший способ доказательства правоты. У меня к Вам только одна просьба, откройте стандарт  IEEE Std 1003.1c-1995, который вводит понятие "поток" и объясните мне, как же несчастные процессы существовали в *NIX системах **до** 1995 года, когда никаких потоков в природе не существовало?

И как существует огромное множество приложений, к которым, при их сборке, не применялся ключ -lthread, кто же в них поддерживает эту призрачную единственную нить?

Comment: @Sergey ну вот с двух подсказок и научились @ знак писать — это не оскорбление это просто констатация факта.  Причём здесь IEEE стандарт какой-то? Цитату приведите, которая противоречит тому что  я сказал, которая к "top H" команде на Linux применима. Подумайте как в течении лет менялась реализация потоков на Linux — каким стандартам она следовала или не  следовала (привести вам цитату Линуса из 90х? Вы знаете, что ядро думало о потоках в то время?)— более того на разных платформах разная реализация может быть. Проверка: что вы думаете PID колонка выше показывает?

Comment: @jfs **Причём здесь IEEE стандарт какой-то?** - я думаю, пора заканчивать дискуссию.

Comment: @Sergey: понятие потоков и до 1995 года существовало. Но я готов был от вас услышать цитату и из стандарта, но вы её ожидаемо не привели и  побоялись упомянуть что PID в таблице означает (мне особо интересно как вы поведение `top H` в отношении этой колонки объясните по стандарту на разных реализациях с 90x годов начиная)¶ Всё это не имеет отношения к вопросу в заголовке. Ответ очевиден. "У меня к Вам только одна просьба," покажите строчку в таблице с нулём потоков на картинке выше (если вы убеждены, что живой процесс ноль потоков может иметь). Выберите PID и скажите: нет потоков, ноль, 0.

Answer (score 3):

Потоки чисто технически не отличаются от процессов - при создании потока создается новый процесс, который наследует ту же память и дескрипторы, что и родитель. Чтобы увидеть такие процессы, нужно слегка настроить `htop`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поставив эти галочки, получим вот такой вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красным отмечены дочерние потоки, которые насоздавала `suricata`. Вы можете видеть, что фактически, это отдельные процессы с разными `PID`. Но при этом, графы, касающиеся используемой памяти, у них заполнены идентично - что подтверждает мое первое утверждение - процесс, реализующий поток наследует от родителя дескрипторы и память.

Comment: Я бы с радостью настроил и команду и понажимал галочки, если б у меня была такая возможность. Но, как я уже писал в первом сообщении-вопросе, у меня есть только скриншот, сделанный на аудиторном компьютере, по которому мне нужно определить эти несчастные потоки.

Но, судя по комментарию, я так понимаю, что в моем случае потоками будут выделенные красным строки?
[Потоки](http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1521003896/4aaa1c10/20948445.png)

Вот прямо все?

Comment: @ago - группы потоков вы выделили неправильно. И что за странный способ изучения ОС - по скриншотам? Поставьте линукс в виртуалку

Answer (score 0):

Есть два внешних признака, позволяющие отличить процесс от потока.

1. У всех потоков одного процесса PPID (родитель) совпадают. Но любой процесс может порождать и процессы и потоки. Поэтому, надо использовать критерий № 2:
2. У всех потоков одного процесса совпадает командная строка, из которой они были запущены. Все потоки запускаются из ОДНОГО исполняемого файла. А вот процессы, как правило, из разных.

На картинке, которую Вы прилагаете нет ни PPID ни командной строки. Поэтому, я думаю, эта задача неразрешима. Что бы на самом деле выполнить поиск потоков, рекомендую следующую последовательность действий:

3. ps -eLf > proc_list.txt
4. В полученном файле удаляем все колонки, кроме PID, PPID и command
5. Сортируем по полю PPID
6. Группируем по Command

Если в некоторой группе будет больше 1 строки, значит все дополнительные - потоки.